# Slow MySQL query using WHERE like

Tags: php, mysql

This is the query I'm using to perform a forum search.

```
$sql = "SELECT t.title, t.user_id, t.replies, t.views, t.last_poster_name, t.last_post_time, a.username
FROM fm_topics t 
LEFT JOIN fm_replies r 
ON t.t_id=r.topic_id 
LEFT JOIN account a 
ON t.user_id=a.id
WHERE 
`title` LIKE '%" . sanitize($search_string) . "%' OR
`content` LIKE '%" . sanitize($search_string) . "%'
GROUP BY t_id LIMIT 0, 10";
```

The above works fine. However, it takes like 5+ seconds to load. Now, if I take out the part where it searches for the title too, it loads way faster (obviously). My question is, how can I improve this query? how would you rewrite it for better performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make a full-text search and index it? That will make searches much faster. By using a `LIKE` query, especially one that is prefix wild-carded it means every row has to be sequentially scanned.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

I would make two-column full-text index on `title,content`:

`CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX index_content ON (title,content)`

Than search on it like:

`SELECT ... WHERE MATCH(title, content) AGAINST ("your query")`

Optionally using `IN BOOLEAN MODE` - read the docs for reasons on why you would and would not use this modifier.

If you really cannot implement a full-text search+index and need to keep the `LIKE` then you can consider just adding a regular index on `content`, but then to take advantage of that index you will have to remove the leading wild-card (you can keep the trailing one); MySQL cannot use an index on a leading-wildcard query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySql functions like `MATCH` and `AGAINST`. By default, the `MATCH()` function performs a natural language search for a string against a text collection. A collection is a set of one or more columns included in a FULLTEXT index. The search string is given as the argument to `AGAINST()`. For each row in the table, `MATCH()` returns a relevance value; that is, a similarity measure between the search string and the text in that row in the columns named in the `MATCH()` list.

[Natural Language Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

The query needs no optimization instead the table might if indexing is not done on that table.

[What is an index in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955459/what-is-an-index-in-sql-server)

And for your scenario, i.e. text searching using wildcard, `Full text indexing` is recommended.

[When should you use full-text indexing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57918/when-should-you-use-full-text-indexing)

Comment: What? Question is asked for `MySql` and not `Sql Server`.

Comment: The link is about concept. Its not about syntax and all.

Comment: True but user may confuse it. So, should be redirected to proper place like indexing in mysql dev document.